# Show all the current files and directories including their statuses

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am trying to learn Git. Right now i am using `LibGit2Sharp` library to play around with my Git repository.

I want to display the current Repository files structure, including the new files that have been added but not yet comitted.

I see that i can get the `Tree` of the latest commit i made:

```
    using (var repo = new Repository(repositoryPath))
    {
        Tree tree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
        TraverseTree(tree);
    }

    void TraverseTree(Tree tree)
    {
        foreach (TreeEntry item in tree.ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Path);

            if (item.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Tree)
            {
                Tree subTree = (Tree)item.Target;
                TraverseTree(subTree);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is possible to fetch the current Reository structure, including the new files using Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to display the current Repository files structure, including the new files that have been added but not yet committed.

It looks like you're after something like **[git status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)**.

This can easily be done with LibGit2Sharp through the `repo.RetrieveStatus()` method.

In order to get a broader understanding of the feature and its use cases, I'd advise you to take a look a the **[StatusFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/bd4e4c9407ed0ac1ad4834ba8493d4d523a18a98/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/StatusFixture.cs)** test suite.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! i still have one question: `repo.RetrieveStatus()` gives me a summary of the modified files. If i want to show the current files tree structure, i will have to traverse actually the folders / files, and update the UI based on the `RepositoryStatus` object? Because Repository Tree only contains what is already staged

Comment: You can find the `Repository.Index` what's staged. The `Repository.Head.Tip.Tree` contains what's been committed. The traversal of the Tree of the Head would allow you to display the content of the Head commit.